# HTTPHandler and svc

Tags: wcf, routes, httphandler, svc

I've got an existing web application, that is installed on several machines. script clients and .net clients consume ".asmx" services through one machine, that routes all calls to other machines.

Client ----> |Website \ Virtual directory(HttpHandler)| ----> |Other server \ real .asmx|

I added a new .svc service that does the same functionality, and added a handler for it (directory's config):

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="MY_ASMX" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="MY.AO.HttpProxy, Astea.AO.HttpProxy" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="MY_ASPX" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="MY.AO.HttpProxy, Astea.AO.HttpProxy" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="MY_WSDL" verb="*" path="*.wsdl" type="MY.AO.HttpProxy, Astea.AO.HttpProxy" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="MY_SVC" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="MY.AO.HttpProxy, Astea.AO.HttpProxy" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

while asmx request are routed fine, my new .svc on the end server does not get called, and even the Httphandler is skipped. if i call the .svc directly on the other machine it works.

the error i get is:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/26458746
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/Mysite/MyDirectory/settings.svc' does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/Mysite/MyDirectory/settings.svc' does not exist.
```

I already tried the folowing

1. add "buildProviders" to compilation section that removes .svc
2. Click on MimeTypes and enter “.svc” and “application/octet-stream” and save
3. add a handler :

nothing helps, http handler is not being called

p.s. Im working with AppPool .net 4.0 Integrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.svc extensions are considered by default to be WCF services, and handlers/modules are already present for them.  You can remove the existing handlers/modules by putting a  element before your `<add>` element:

```
<remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
```

(or, if on win64:)

```
<remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
```

And, in the `<modules>` element:

```
<remove name="ServiceModel-4.0" />
```

Comment: already tried  <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" /> and that has no affect... other extensions get caught, but .svc doesn't.

Comment: I also tried to remove all other handler mappings that are in the IIS handler mappings for this site, with no luck

Comment: Also, get rid of this http module from the <modules> section:  <remove name="ServiceModel-4.0" />

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. Adding:

```
<compilation debug="true" >
  <buildProviders>
    <remove extension=".svc"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

caused an error, that got me to back off, at the first time:
"~/ServiceManagement.svc" demanded that the buildProvider for ".svc" will be on

"~/ServiceManagement.svc" is automatiacally created in the machine root config when you install MS AppFabric. Since I'm using that folder only for redirection, I don't need Appfabric there, so I removed it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <remove relativeAddress="~/ServiceManagement.svc"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```